# Python pandas: How to efficiently aggregate categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data with an id and a value, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
    "value": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"]
})
df
```

[image]

As seen above, the id can occure multiple times. I want to aggregate the data from each id into one row, to get something like this:

[image]

I have code that accomplishes that in two steps. First I add the count to each row:

```
counts = df.groupby("id")["value"].value_counts()
def get_counts(x, instance):
    try:
        return counts.loc[x["id"], instance]
    except:
        return 0

for i in df["value"].unique():
    df["value_count_" + i] = df.apply(lambda x: get_counts(x, i), axis=1)
df
```

[image]

Then I drop the `value` column and then the duplicates:

```
df.drop(columns="value").drop_duplicates()
```

[image]

However, although this works, it takes a lot of time for larger datasets and I'm sure there is a more efficient way to get the counts in the first step.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: crosstab? `pd.crosstab(df['id'],df['value']).add_prefix("value_counts_").reset_index()` or even pivot table with `aggfunc='size`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe refer question 9